# I have one text file and in that text file I stored words in 2 columns. I want to store first column in one array and second column in another array

Tags: java

I separate two columns by tab. I have done following code for that but with that code I got one column in one array as a whole. I want to access each element individually and I want to store two columns in two arrays using java.

In `splitting[0]`, I have first array and in `splitting[1]` I stored second column elements. Now I want to access each element individually using Java.

```
for(int i=0;i<lines.size();i++){
    String[] splitting = lines.get(i).split("\t");
}
```

Comment: Sorry I do not understand what you mean - please edit your question to make it understandable.  Maybe provide sample data and expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create two more arrays.

Put this after your split.

```
array1[i] = splitting[0];
array2[i] = splitting[1];`
```

You need to set the size of the two new arrays to `lines.size()`. I would use `List` instead of `Array`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Scanner to specify delimiter as tab..and use dynamic array i.e. ArrayList for adding columns.

```
BufferedReader reader= new BufferedReader(new FileReader("D:/sagar.txt"));
        Scanner sc= new Scanner(reader);
        sc.useDelimiter("\\s+"); // regex for specifying one or more tabs

        List<String> a=new ArrayList<String>();
        List<String> b =new ArrayList<String>();
        while((sc.hasNextLine())){
            a.add(sc.next());
            b.add(sc.next());
        }

        System.out.println("First Column");

        for (String string : a) {

            System.out.println(string);
        }

        System.out.println("Second Column");
        for (String string : b) {
            System.out.println(string);
```

sagar.txt

```
hi ssup 
hello gm
```

Comment: When I use above code I am getting following error.                 Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
 at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:862)
 at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1371)
 at javaapplication1.CellTest.main(CellTest.java:42)

Comment: did you create text file with tab separated values as i mentioned? Each line is considered to be a new record with 2 different column values assuming this is what you're looking for.